# Notarization of MacOS Eclipse RCP Application

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-rcp, tycho, notarization

We want to notarize our Eclipse RCP Application. At present we build the eclipse application with tycho(maven)

```
tycho-p2-director-plugin:1.6.0:materialize-products (materialize-products) @ <product file>.product ---
```

In our codebase there is a template .app file which we have pre-codesigned. During the build process the binary gets replaced by an unsigned eclipse.

```
Installing product <product file>.product for environment macosx/cocoa/x86_64 to <path
to .app which is already codesigned>
```

Are there any maven plugins in place with we could codesign the eclipse application once the product is installed, before creating the zips?

I came across the eclipse cbi project but it looks like it is internal to the eclipse community and the service is not reachable. Also when we unpack the zip and codesign the product gets corrupted.

Comment: We were able to resolve this error by adding the entitlements file for the binary after the zip creation. 

` 
<key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
      <true/>
`